# How can I combine my Setup project and Bootstrapper project in WiX?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I have created an msi installer using the WiX setup project, and I also have a Bootstrapper project where I have all the other pre requisites for the installation of the msi installer. Instead of having two separate projects- one for creating an msi installer and one for bundling all the dependencies together- can I combine all of this in just a single project?

I have two codes currently- bundle.wxs for the bootstrapper, and product.wxs for the installer. I am hopingto have just one wxs file with all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiX isn't designed to support that.  One wxs builds the MSI and then the other builds the EXE that knows and possibly embeds the MSI.  Two different layers of the solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just a follow-up question, is there any other template I could use in WiX which would allow me to do both the things within one project?

Comment: I'm afraid the question doesn't make sense in the context of WiX.

Comment: I have an open source project you might be interested in as a learning excercise. I have a tutorial available here.  Pick the tutorial closest to that your doing but instead of picking IsWiX Solution for WiX v4 pick IsWiX Bootstrapper Solution for WiX v3.  You'll see a solution get created with multiple projects. This might explain things a bit.  I offer complimentary 1 hour training sessions.

Comment: Where can I check out the tutorial you mention of?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I didn't add the link. It's https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

Answer (score 1):

It's something I've considered adding to WiX but it is not implemented. It is not high priority so there is also no schedule for it to be implemented.